# Air resistance in experiment about measuring Gravitational acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, drag

In my experiment, I use MBL sensor and drop volleyball and tennis ball and I measure gravity acceleration. But mechanical energy wasn't preserved because of [air resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29). I found two expressions:

$$ F = \tfrac{1}{2}\,\rho\,v^2\,C_d\,A $$

and:

$$F=bv$$

Which one is right? And I saw that $C_d$ is usually $0.4$ in turbulence with sphere shape. Can it be applied in this experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with problems in fluid mechanics there are always two different types of forces to be considered: viscous forces and inertial forces.

Viscous forces arise when you're trying to move in something that is gooey. For example it's easy to move in water than it is to move in treacle because water is less viscous.

Inertial forces arise when you're trying to push a fluid out of the way. To move through a fluid I have to push it out of my way, and that means I have to accelerate it. Newton's second law tells that to accelerate a mass $m$ by an amount $a$ takes a force $F = ma$, so pushing the fluid out of the way requires a force that we call the inertial force.

As a guideline, when you are moving slowly in the fluid you aren't accelerating the fluid much so the inertial forces are small, and in that case the drag is dominated by the viscous force. In this regime the drag on a sphere is given by [Stokes' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law):

$$ F = 6\pi\,\eta\,r\,v \tag{1} $$

where $\eta$ is the viscosity. Note that the density of the fluid doesn't appear in this equation. This equation is the same as your second equation, where your constant $b = 6\pi\,\eta\,r$.

When you are moving fast in the fluid you are accelerating the fluid a lot and the drag is dominated by inertial forces. This gives us the [quadratic drag law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Drag_at_high_velocity):

$$ F = \tfrac{1}{2}\,\rho\,v^2\,C_d\,A \tag{2} $$

where $\rho$ is the fluid density. Note that this time the viscosity doesn't appear in the equation.

So which equation you use depends on the speed you are using. More precisely it depends on the [Reynold's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number), since this is just the ratio of the inertial to viscous forces.

To check which equation you should use you need to calculate the Reynolds number. However there is no need to do that since as a general rule unless you are moving very slowly the Reynolds number will be high and inertial forces dominate. Your experiment is no exception and you need to use the quadratic drag equation i.e. equation (2) above.

The drag coefficient $C_d$ is actually not a constant and depends on the sphere velocity. See [this article by NASA](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/dragsphere.html) for an overview of how $C_d$ changes with Reynold's number. However for most purposes you can take the value of $C_d$ to be 0.5.